# Is it possible to add an arbitrary folder to the current project In Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, project, clion

I have a project in Qt Creator. I want to debug the behavior of interaction with other project. Let's say I am launching dolphin (file manager), and want to add breakpoints in the ark's (archiver) project files.
I can open ark's project file directly and place breakpoint there. But I want the files to be always at my view.

In CLion it is [possible](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-12785/Allow-adding-several-content-sources-roots) to add an arbitrary folder with such change to `.idea/misc.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CMakeWorkspace" PROJECT_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
  <component name="CidrRootsConfiguration">
    <sourceRoots>
      <file path="$PROJECT_DIR$/<relative path to the source/header dirs>" />
    </sourceRoots>
  </component>
</project>
```

[image: arbitrary folder added to project]

Is the same possible with Qt Creator? I do not want to edit the `CMakeLists.txt`. And of course, I do not want files to be added individually. I know the Qt Creator stores configuration in `CMakeLists.txt.user`. Is there a way to include directory by similar approach?

Also, I tried to right click the project in project tree, but all these menu entries are greyed out. (Add New, Add Existing Files, Add Existing Projects, Add Existing Directory, New Subproject, Add Library).

[image: greyed out entries to add to project]

Do they work only for .pro (qmake) projects, and not cmake projects?

Also, in the Projects | Project Settings | Dependencies I cannot add anything (no reaction on clicking there).

Also, I have seen screenshots of Qt Creator with folders named `<Other Locations>`, `<External Dependencies>`. How to just create such a folder with your specified path?